# Getting some strange data from an MPU-6050

Tags: mpu6050

I'm trying to create an IMU unit using MPU-6050 unit.

I've got 100k data records, and this is the result:

[image: Gyro x,y,z readings]

It seems to me that's a kind of offset in gx. Why?

[image: Accel x,y,z]

Why I'm getting this kind of drifting in acz?

This is the setup code:

```
void setup_mpu_6050_registers(){

  //Activate the MPU-6050
  
  //Start communicating with the MPU-6050
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); 
  //Send the requested starting register                                       
  Wire.write(0x6B);  
  //Set the requested starting register                                                  
  Wire.write(0x00);
  //End the transmission                                                    
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
                                              
  //Configure the accelerometer (+/-8g)
  
  //Start communicating with the MPU-6050
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); 
  //Send the requested starting register                                       
  Wire.write(0x1C);   
  //Set the requested starting register                                                 
  Wire.write(0x10); 
  //End the transmission                                                   
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
                                              
  //Configure the gyro (500dps full scale)
  
  //Start communicating with the MPU-6050
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  //Send the requested starting register                                        
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  //Set the requested starting register                                                    
  Wire.write(0x08); 
  //End the transmission                                                  
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
                                              
}
```

And this is the reading code:

```
void read_mpu_6050_data(){ 

  //Read the raw gyro and accelerometer data

  //Start communicating with the MPU-6050                                          
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);  
  //Send the requested starting register                                      
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  //End the transmission                                                    
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  //Request 14 bytes from the MPU-6050                                  
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,14);    
  //Wait until all the bytes are received                                       
  while(Wire.available() < 14);
  
  //Following statements left shift 8 bits, then bitwise OR.  
  //Turns two 8-bit values into one 16-bit value                                       
  myData.msecs = millis();
  myData.acc_x = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                  
  myData.acc_y = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                  
  myData.acc_z = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                  
  myData.temp = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                   
  myData.gyro_x = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                 
  myData.gyro_y = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                 
  myData.gyro_z = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                                 
}
```

The structure that stores data is:

```
struct datastore {
   long msecs;
   int acc_x, acc_y, acc_z;
   int temp;
   int gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z;
};
```

Then I save data in the card:

```
logFile.write((const uint8_t *)&myData, sizeof(myData));
```

Comment: where do the graphs come from? ... how is the data in the graphs selected? ... maybe you are graphing an incorrect parameter

Comment: The graphs were made based on data saved on a CSV file in a SD card connected to arduino.

Comment: I changed the question including the data structure that's is used to store data and the code that save it.

Comment: The graphs show values much larger than can be stored in an int. Could you show a line from your CSV file?